# Accept multiple predicates as argument to method

Tags: java, generics, predicate

I'm pretty new to Java and following a course to understand it better. In the `Test code` below we are supposed to be able to create a method that accepts multiple `Predicate`. I can't seem to get it right. `Collections` seem logical but they can't be used. so I thought `Predicate<T>[] predicates` would suffice. But no success there.

```
public class Utils {
//    public static <T> Predicate<T> anyPassPredicate(Predicate<T>[] predicates) {
    public static <T> Predicate<T> anyPassPredicate(Collection<Predicate<T>> predicates) {
        Predicate<T> pred = predicates.stream().reduce(Predicate::or).orElse(x->false);;
        return pred;
    }

    public static <T> T firstAnyMatch(List<T> list, Predicate<T> predicate) {
        for (T element : list) {
            if (predicate.test(element)) {
                return element;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> words = Arrays.asList("Jan", "Jos", "Anna", "Pieter", "Johan");
        Predicate<String> anyMatch = Utils.anyPassPredicate(s -> s.contains("o"), s -> s.length() > 5);
        Utils.firstAnyMatch(words, anyMatch);
    }
}
```

How is it possible to accept multiple `Predicate` as argument to the method?

Comment: You're probably looking for varargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a method to accept an unspecified number of arguments of the same type, you need to use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), which is specified by an ellipsis

```
static <T> Predicate<T> anyPassPredicate(Predicate<T>... predicates) {
    return Arrays.stream(predicates)
         .reduce(Predicate::or)
         .orElse(x->false);
}
```

Comment: Thx Yosef. that fixed it indeed.

Comment: you might want to annotate it with `SafeVarargs`